# bash extract string from line of text

Tags: regex, bash, grep, echo

I need to extract a serial number that can occur anywhere on a line. The serial number always has the following regex format:

```
S[XN]00-[0-9]{3}
```

Output:

```
SX00-123
```

I want to `echo` this only. I can `grep` the serial number and was thinking of a using a regex but not sure how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try `grep`,

```
grep -oE 'S[XN]00-[0-9]{3}' file
```

From `grep --help`,

```
-E, --extended-regexp     PATTERN is an extended regular expression (ERE)
-o, --only-matching       show only the part of a line matching PATTERN
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat test.txt 
randomtextSX00-456
SX00-164randomtext
randomtextSX00-184randomtext
SX00-986
randomtext
```

---

```
$ grep -oE 'S[XN]00-[0-9]{3}' test.txt 
SX00-456
SX00-164
SX00-184
SX00-986
```

Comment: Maybe write an explanation on why OP should use the `-E` and `-o` option.........